# is there any way to generate dynamic css styles in react like make-styles but simpler?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was looking in for a way to dynamically generate a stylesheet for specific parts of a component that already rely on css for specific things. I was wondering how I could create styles that use compound selectors without dynamically depending on the state of the component (the number of children to render for ex).

I found that material-ui and other libs uses this make-styles or styled-components.
Are there any simpler/hacky implementations of that same principle?

Thanks

Comment: You want something like material make-styles which generate component specific css?

Comment: yes, but in a few lines or anything else that people already do without having to import that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS modules in React for component specific styles.
Make a css file and name it *.module.css

Example:

```
firstComponent.module.css

  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
  .firstChild {
    flex: 1;
  }
```

In your .tsx or .jsx file:

```
import style from './firstComponent.module.css';

const FirstComponent = () => {
   return (
     <div className={style.container}> 
       <div className={style.firstChild}>First child</div>
     </div
   )
}
```

Comment: That is what I don't want to do, if you are importing a style you can't dynamically generate it. This is why people use makestyles, so they don't have to import a static css.